# Combining multiple background-images with different selectors

Tags: html, css

In css 3 you can apply multiple backgrounds to an element like this for example:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
```

Is there a way that in another selector I can add a background?

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
p {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}

p.one {
    background-image: url("/somepicture.png");
}

p.two {
    background-image: url("/someotherpicture.png");
}
```

The intent here is that a `p`-tag with class `one` has the gradient, but also the image and with `two` also the gradient + a different image.

Obviously the above syntax just overwrites the brackground-image, so that doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this in CSS3?

Comment: I think you have to repeat all the same backgrounds (that means no way in CSS3, there's possibly a shorter way with SCSS but I'm not sure).

Comment: The thing is that `someotherpicture` is dynamic, so it will be defined inline

Comment: @Kenneth You mean with a style attribute? That wouldn't make a difference; you will still need to put in the original background as well.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was hoping to avoid that, but I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 0):

You can try an workaround and set p tag display property to block and it's position relative. Then add an before or after pseudo-element styled with your desired gradient.